# System.exit(0) Is not working

Tags: java

```
try
    {    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new 
                                           InputStreamReader(System.in));
         int t=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
         if (t <0 && t>11) System.exit(0);
         for (int i = 0; i<t;i++){
             int count=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); 
             if (count <1 && count>101) System.exit(0);
            .
            .
    }catch(Exception e){}
  }
```

If count >= 102 the program is not terminating can anyone suggest me what to do and why? neither for t >=11

Comment: Because count isn't less than 1.

Comment: how can `t` be both `if (t <0 && t>11)` ?

Comment: How can `count` be both less than 1 and greater than 101?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (t <0 && t>11) System.exit(0);
```

A number can't be smaller than 0 and bigger than 11 at the same point in time. Or to be precise: the numerical types that Java support don't allow for that.

In that sense, you probably meant:

```
if (numberFromUser < 0 || numberFromUser > 11) {
 System.out.println("number " + numberFromUser + " is invalid, exiting");
 System.exit(1);
}
```

And please note changes I made:

- `t` is an absolutely pointless name - use names that *mean* something
- always always always use {  braces } - even for such simple one line statemeents
- just exiting is a **bad** idea: you want to give the user **feedback** what went wrong. Or do you like it when your computer just stops something doing without telling you why?
- and then: you have an **empty** catch block - another super bad idea. There is no point in **suppressing** error messages. Aren't you interested in understanding when your program runs into errors?!
- The value passed to `System.exit()` is the "return code" of your application. And by convention, returning **zero** means: all fine, passed. Thus you should return something other than zero in error cases.

And finally: using `System.exit()` all over the place is by itself *bad practice*. You really do not want that your application has more than **one** `exit()` point. In other words: you should design your whole application to use exceptions for example. When there are real "hard" problems - give a good message to the user, and throw an exception (which maybe your top layer catches and turns into a meaningful, defined non-zero return code).

Comment: @ScaryWombat That is why my answer includes additional elements, not to be found in other answers ;-)

Comment: Yep, it does now. I like your other points.

Comment: @ScaryWombat https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/146/legendary

Comment: @ScaryWombat Your contribution is noted ;-) ... rest assured, when the big day comes, there will be one huge upvote party. And you just got invited...

Comment: Since you added best practices to your answer, it's worth noting that the exit code `0` is considered as OK. So outputting an error message and returning with the OK-exit-code is a contradiction. Should be `System.exit(1)` or something similar.

Comment: @Lothar Makes a lot of sense. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`count` cannot be smaller than 0 and greater than 11 at the same time.

Comment: actually, this is the test for t, the count should be less than 1 and greater than 101

Answer (score 0):

This condition is never satisfied:

```
if (count <1 && count>101) System.exit(0);
```

`count` can't be both smaller than `1` and greater than `101`